# How to get Eclipse to autocomplete custom widgets names in XML files

Tags: android, eclipse, android-custom-view

Built-in widgets get autocomplete by the content assist in Eclipse. But, AFAIK, custom widgets are not completed, not even checked, so if you write the widget URL with some typo you will only discover it at runtime, not even at compilation time.
How can I make Eclipse to content assist also my custom widgets?

For example:

```
...

<CheckBoxPreference
   android:key="@+id/mykey"
   ... />

<comm.example.lib.myCustomPreference
   ... />

...
```

The typo **"comm..."** will not be detected until you try to use the custom widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as far as i know we cant autocomplete the custom widget names in eclipse but we can detect at compile time.

We just need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and click on the **widget name**.If that widget **exist** it will **take you to that custom widget class** but if not then it will not show you that custom widget class.So this is how you can find out at compile time that you written the correct custom widget name or not..!

Comment: I actually have a similar code as I described, and I only discovered the typo I had, when I tried to use the widget. Regarding your suggestion, it does work, also just putting the cursor on the widget URL will open a small window with its URL and description, if it exist, if it does not open anything, it means it did not find it. All this is good, and practical, but I wish I could get an automatic error message without having to do it manually.

Comment: not available but wish this feature come in new build of eclipse..!